# Is there any function in sql server that replace 0 instead of negative value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-update, sql-function

If `First_Session` were bigger than current date, `Learning_Time` would be negative; which is not possible.

Is there any function that handles these types of negative values??
Your answer would be helpful

```
UPDATE Is_Learning 
SET Learning_Time = 
    (SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, 
        (SELECT MIN(C.First_Session)
        From Class C
        WHERE C.c_StudentID = @Student_Id
            AND C.c_InstrumentID = @Instrument_ID)
        , GETDATE()))
WHERE l_StudentID = @Student_Id
    AND l_InstrumentID = @Instrument_ID
```

Comment: Have you considered a `case expression` or `iif()`?

Comment: yeah, I've considered it but I was looking for a function just like ISNULL() that handles negative value automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by handles a negative automatically..? What, exactly, is wrong with an `IIF` or `CASE` expression?

Comment: Why not just write a scalar function to do the job?

Comment: Because they tend to be terribly slow, @Stu (unless the OP is using 2019, where it could likely be inlined, but they've tagged a version that has been *completely* unsupported for **3 years**).

Comment: Why would `First_Session` be in the future? If the first session hasn't occurred yet, shouldn't `Learning_Time` be left empty, and not be updated at all?

Comment: Scalar functions are potentially slow of course over large result sets but would be fine in the OP's one-row update example.

Comment: Speaking of supported versions, the OP won't be able to use `IIF`; the function is only available in supported versions of SQL Server.

Comment: this has nothing to do woth your problem but 2008 is reay realy old and should be urgently updated